# Prevent applications from enabling taskbar autohide (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: windows-7

Is there a posibility to prevent applications from setting autohide to taskbar?
GPedit prevention do not work for application (only for users from gui).
Most of the tested registry hacking do not work or do nothing.
Goole not helping...

Comment: Creating a lop in application is not a solution since i need to prevent _application_ form changeing taskbar authide option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, by creating a loop that checks the current status of the task bar.

If the status is A, start loop.

If the status is C, change to A and start loop.

It would be easy to make an .exe to change the status to A everytime it is set to B.